# pre_comment_content filter not working using IntenseDebate Enhanced moderation

Tags: comments

I wrote a plugin that modifies the contents of some comments. It uses the pre_comment_content filter. It seems to work OK using the standard WP moderation, however, it doesn't when I turn on the IntenseDebate Enhanced Moderation.

Here's some code:

```
function my_plugin($orig_comment){

  $orig_comment = some_func($orig_comment);

 return $orig_comment;
}
```

Edit: Basically the plugin just applies some formatting, let's say lowercase all letters. In the first case it works perfectly, when using IntenseDebate it seems as if my function never gets called.

Any workarounds for this?

Comment: We'll need more information on what your plugin does. Also, what exactly doesn't work? Any error messages or just a blank spot where IntenseDebate comments should be?

Comment: Yeah, let me expand on the details.

Answer (score 1):

You write "it seems as if my function never gets called". I would at first verify if that's the case or not, e.g. by testing wether or not that is the case (print statements, debugger).

If your hook really is not called any longer than some other plugin might remove your hook. If thats the case, the code that removes the hook must be reverse engineered to create a counter-strategy against that plugins behavior.

It might be the case that your hook is removed by error by the other plugin. If that's the case, please fill a bugreport to the other plugin and/or WordPress.

If you plugin still is called but your output is ignored, it might help to change the priority you hook is using. Additionally sometime an alternative hook is available which still does the job regardless of interference by other plugins.

I know my answer is not very concrete but you did not provide much factual infos to build something on. So this is just for a starter.